# Problemas al Actualizar PHP

Tags: php, laragon

mi problema es que hasta hace poco yo usaba la versión 7.4 de PHP. Pero, me intereso usar Laravel y para usar el comando PHP Artisan, me pedía trabajar con una versión de PHP 8 o superior. Entonces, eso hice uso Laragon y la actualice.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coloque la carpeta de la nueva versión de PHP en Laragon, pero cuando reviso en la consola sigo teniendo la misma versión. 7.4 ¿Como lo solucionó para que me tome la nueva versión? Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Como estás usando Laravel también estás usando Composer. Cuando instalas Composer este te pregunta qué versión de PHP quieres usar (de las versiones que tienes instaladas), y agrega esa versión al PATH en las variables de entorno del sistema, por más que instales nuevas versiones Composer/Laravel tomará la versión que tienes configurada en el PATH.

Simplemente configura tu PATH (en las variables de entorno del sistema) para que apunte a la nueva instalación de PHP.

[image: Ruta de instalación de PHP 8 en las variables del sistema]